# Conductive Thread - non toxic?

Tags: conductive, thread

Is the [conductive thread](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product%5Finfo.php?products%5Fid=8549) non toxic?

Safe to wear up against your skin for extended periods of time?

Comment: non-toxic should probably be combined into one tag

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that the thread sold by Sparkfun is made by [ShieldEx](http://www.shieldextrading.net). According to the [material safety data sheet](http://www.shieldextrading.net/images/pdfs/STATEX%5F%5F%5FMATERIAL%5FSAFETY%5FDATA%5FAg.pdf) for the silver-coated thread:

> Eye Protection: SHIELDEX® silver
>   coated non-woven/or/woven nylon fabric
>   and yarns does not cause significant
>   eye irritation or eye toxicity
>   requiring special protection. Use good
>   industrial practice to avoid eye
>   contact.
>
> Skin Protection: SHIELDEX®
>   silver-coated non-woven/or/woven nylon
>   fabric and yarns does not present a
>   significant skin concern requiring
>   special protection.

Comprehensive [review](http://www.fashioningtech.com/page/conductive-thread) of other conductive threads

Comment: That's for handling during industrial assembly, though, isn't it?  Not for wearing on a daily basis.

Comment: according to the MSDS: "Skin contact is expected to be the primary route of occupational exposure to SHIELDEX® silver coated non- woven/or/woven nylon fabric and yarns. Occupational exposure to this material has not been reported to cause significant adverse health effects" - I haven't used the thread to be able to give a definitive but you can always consult with the company before using